# Fundamental theorem of calculus for the Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let

- $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
- $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $\lambda$-integrable

What's the easiest way to show $$\frac d{dx}\int_{[0,x]}f\;d\lambda=f(x)\;\;\;\text{for }\lambda\text{-almost every }x\in\mathbb{R}\;?$$

Comment: aka the Lebesgue differentiation theorem - not an easy result to obtain.

Comment: Did you have some problem understanding the proof in your textbook on measure theory?  Wasn't there a question here recently about "what good is the Vitali covering theorem"?  Well, maybe that guy should look here!